# Pronunciation of "practical" and "miracle"

Tags: pronunciation

I just checked from the Cambridge online dictionary, I found out that written pronunciations of "practical" and "miracle" are

/ˈpræk.tɪ.**kəl**/

and

/ˈmɪr.ɪ.**kl̩**/

I've always thought "cal" and "cle" are pronounced the same, but I can't really tell difference by listening. So can anyone tell me the difference?

Comment: The spelling is arbitrary, and has nothing to do with minutiae of pronounciation. /kəl/ and /kl̩/ are just two different ways of transcribing a reduced syllable ending in a resonant. Similar problems arise with _-er_. Final unstressed resonants can either be syllabic themselves (the underdot /l/ or /r/) or they can have a reduced central vowel /ə/ followed by a postvocalic resonant. People alternate, depending on how fast and interested and irritated and ... other things they are. The dictionary should probly choose one or the other phonemic transcription to avoid this phonemic confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***There is no difference*** in pronunciation between the last syllables of practical and miracle. There may have been when English spelling was codified, but I suspect even this wasn't true.

There is a difference in pronunciation between /-kəl/ and /-kl̩/. However, these are allophones in English, meaning that no words are distinguished by this difference.  Which one people use may depend on their dialects (or on how fast they're speaking). However, I suspect most people use the same pronunciation for *practical* and *miracle*. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/practical) seems to think that Americans say /-kəl/, /-pəl/, /tʃəl/, and /-tl̩/ for words ending in these syllables (e.g. *fickle, apple, satchel, chattel*). But it's certainly not true that all Americans follow this rule.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't rely too strongly upon the written pronunciation in any dictionary.  As Captain Barbossa of The Black Pearl said of the Pirate's Code: "It's more of a guideline than a rule."

I am an American English speaker living on the Northwest coast of the US.  I pronounce the final syllable in these words exactly the same. Others may pronounce them differently from how Cambridge indicates as well, but differently from me. Cambridge is located in England, after all, and the online dictionary may be indicating how they are pronounced in British *Received Pronunciation* (RP).